# Watching a variable whose value keep on changing

Tags: c#, c++, debugging

my question is related to debugging in VS 2010.i am creating an App in OpenGL using Kinect,As the x,y,z cordinates keep on changing so i want to keep track of each x,y,z coordinate.If you put a breakpoint at a certain expression then You have to click some  `STEP OUT or STEP OVER` to again see the next value of variable.Is this possible to get the value of a variable at each instance without stopping the program?

Comment: So how do you intend to read the coordinates without them stoping?

Comment: You should be able to write to the output window in Visual Studio while you are debugging.  Debug.WriteLine().

Comment: @lezebulon as you see in Image processing Apps we can't stop the program again and again and check the x,y,z ..i just want to keep an eye on the x,y,z cordinates while the program is running..

Comment: @EmmieGabrielleLewis I had disabled the console and working on GLUT window

Comment: Why not simply show the x,y,z text on GLUT window?

Comment: @enthusiasticgeek GLUT window doesn't show text,we have to do rendering

Comment: I have used gtkmm using gtkglextmm instead of GLUT a few years back. It did render text. Otherwise Joe's answer is the only choice at this juncture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's a watchpoint.

Set the breakpoint like normal, right click and choose (look out - here's the magic): When Hit.

From that dialog: Print a message, and then set it to something like: Coords: {x}, {y}, {z}

Note the bracing is how you specify to sub in a symbol value.

All output will show up in the debug output window and now you can set these anywhere anytime without having to use an API or recompile.

Comment: ⁻¹, this is not a watchpoint. Watchpoint is a kind of breakpoint that when set to a variable, being triggered when the variable either read or changed. What you're explaining here is a simple breakpoint *(i.e. in a code, not in value)* that checks for a condition. In order to emulate a watchpoint with a breakpoint you ought to set a conditional breakpoint in every single place of a code where the variable is seen.